# iBatis to myBatis conversion related issue

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, is-empty

I have been trying to migrate from ibatis to mybatis. what is the converted equivalent to isEmpty tag of ibatis in mybatis
for isNotEmpty it is 
is this is correct fot isEmpty tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<if test='str=null or str=""'>
```

you may even try something like:

```
<if test='org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(str)'>
```

Comment: how abt this? <if test="str=='' ">

Comment: simple quotes are for character comparaison, so it could work, but beware unexpected of behavior.